# Observe multiple shiny inputs in a div with an id

Tags: r, shiny

#### Problem Statement:

Say I have multiple inputs in a `wellPanel` which has `id = "my_inputs"`. Below the wellPanel is a button labelled "Calculate".

The button is only enabled if all user inputs are valid ie. Not blanks and Not `NULL`.

To do that I've had to check the validity of each of them, one by one using:

```
valid_inputs <- reactive({
    inputs <- c(input$input1, input$input2, input$input3)
    
    purrr::map_lgl(.x = inputs, .f = is_valid) |> all()
  })
```

That works fine. The problem is that I have 3 tabs each with 10 inputs and typing out `c(input$input1, input$input2, input$input3, ..., input$input10)` is kind of tiring considering the inputId's are different and NOT sequential. Also, each tab has its own different inputs so they are not similar.

#### Question:

Is there a way to check for the inputs' validity using the id of the wellPanel?

Something along the lines of:

```
is_valid(id = "my_inputs")
```

#### Reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  wellPanel(
    id = "my_inputs", 
    
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 4, 
        
        selectInput(
          inputId = "input1", 
          label = "Input 1", 
          choices = letters[1:3]
        )
      ), 
      
      column(
        width = 4, 
        
        textInput(
          inputId = "input2", 
          label = "Input 2", 
          placeholder = "Enter name"
        )
      ), 
      
      column(
        width = 4, 
        
        selectInput(
          inputId = "input3", 
          label = "Input 3",
          choices = c("", letters[4:6])
        )
      )
    )
  ), 
  
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12, 
      align = "center", 
      
      actionButton(
        inputId = "actionbtn", 
        label = "Calculate", 
        class = "btn-success"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # fn to check if an input is valid:
  is_valid <- function(x) {
    x != "" && !is.null(x) # input should NOT be blank or NULL
  }
  
  # Map that function over all inputs:
  valid_inputs <- reactive({
    inputs <- c(input$input1, input$input2, input$input3)
    
    purrr::map_lgl(.x = inputs, .f = is_valid) |> all()
  })
  
  # if all inputs are valid, enable calculate btn, else disable:
  observe(
    shinyjs::toggleState(
      id = "actionbtn", 
      condition = valid_inputs()
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There is a default shiny functionality that checks input validity called 'req'. Take a look https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/req.html. As for your question; you can't use the div id to check the inputs directly as it is not a shint input. Are the inputs the same across all tabs? If so, you could write a module.

Comment: Even with `req` I'd still have to type out all my inputId's. And I don't want that. The reason I have a custom function for checking input validity is because there are other things I'm checking as well. @SEcker

Comment: @SEcker The inputs are different across the tabs as well, so a module wouldn't help.

Comment: The new [{litter}](https://github.com/devOpifex/litter) package might help. I'm note sure whether if helps you with validating your inputs, but it definitely solves the observing part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach using `tagQuery` from `library(htmltools)` to extract the id's of wellPanel's children.

To test the inputs you can simply use `shiny::isTruthy`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmltools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  wellPanel(
    id = "wP1", 
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 4, 
        selectInput(
          inputId = "input1", 
          label = "Input 1", 
          choices = letters[1:3]
        )
      ), 
      column(
        width = 4, 
        textInput(
          inputId = "input2", 
          label = "Input 2", 
          placeholder = "Enter name"
        )
      ), 
      column(
        width = 4, 
        selectInput(
          inputId = "input3", 
          label = "Input 3",
          choices = c("", letters[4:6])
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12, 
      align = "center", 
      actionButton(
        inputId = "actionbtn", 
        label = "Calculate", 
        class = "btn-success"
      )
    )
  )
)

wP1Containers <- tagQuery(ui)$find("#wP1")$find("div.shiny-input-container")
wP1InputTags <- c(wP1Containers$find("input")$selectedTags(), wP1Containers$find("select")$selectedTags())
wP1InputIDs <- sapply(wP1InputTags, tagGetAttribute, attr = "id")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    valid_inputs <- all(sapply(wP1InputIDs, function(x){isTruthy(input[[x]])}))
    shinyjs::toggleState(
      id = "actionbtn", 
      condition = valid_inputs
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[Here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3248) is a related issue.

Another approach would be to use a prefix or suffix to identify those input ID's in `session$input` via `grep` and check if `isTruthy` via `lapply`.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful. Didn't know I could use `isTruthy`!

Comment: @Mwavu sure, however, regarding your question the `tagQuery`-part of the answer is more important.

Comment: Yeah, true. It's just that `isTruthy` caught me by surprise here. @ismirsehregal

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can grab the input ids with `reactiveValuesToList`, and apply your validation function to each element.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Capture all input ids
  ui_inputs <- reactive({
    x <- names(reactiveValuesToList(input))
    x[startsWith(x, "input")] # ignore actionbtn
  }) 
  
  
  # fn to check if an input is valid:
  is_valid <- function(x) {
    x != "" && !is.null(x) # input should NOT be blank or NULL
  }
  
  # Check if all input ids are valid using your function
  valid_inputs <- reactive({
     x <- lapply(ui_inputs(), function(x) is_valid(input[[x]]) )
     all(x)
  })
  
  # if all inputs are valid, enable calculate btn, else disable:
  observe(
    shinyjs::toggleState(
      id = "actionbtn", 
      condition = valid_inputs()
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```